# Exchange (Mail) Drag and Drop eMail in Internet Explorer (10)

Tags: javascript, outlook, drag-and-drop, office365, exchange-server

I want to drag and drop an eMail from Office365 (Outlook)
to another browser window.

The problem is that after I select and drag an email to my drop location, it doesn't accept the drop location. (Only in IE, chrome works)

How can I create a drop location which accepts the eMail?

I had a look at: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/ 
but there the dragged objects are never locked this way.

Then I had a look at the different implementations of the drag and drop functionality at this site: http://mereskin.github.io/dnd/

In Chrome the following code works:
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/puq3y6u1/

(JavaScript for the DropLocation)

```
var dropbox = document.getElementById('dropbox');

dropbox.addEventListener('dragenter', noopHandler, false);
dropbox.addEventListener('dragexit', noopHandler, false);
dropbox.addEventListener('dragover', noopHandler, false);
dropbox.addEventListener('drop', drop, false);

function noopHandler(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
}

function drop(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var data = evt.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    console.log(data);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drag and Drop the Office365 Mail</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="dropbox">DropZone </div>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#dropbox {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

I know that for the Internet Explorer the getData type should be changed to "text" only.

However I can't change the setData to "text" only because that is already implemented by the owa site.

When I try to move a mail into the droplocation via chrome it works as expected.

If I try to move a mail from a Internet Explorer Window to a Internet Explorer Window gets instantly blocked the moment I am not on the navigation bar where the folders are.

I tried to Debug how Owa does it. Because you can drag and drop eMails to Folders (in IE). But I got stuck there. The code is minified and very large for me to analyze it.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome Debug Event]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you drag an eMail in Outlook Web App or Exchange with the Internet Explorer it gets copied into the clipboard.

With:

```
window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
```

you can get the data. However you need to enable the clipboard option in the Internet Security Policy Settings.